Can one identify the uses of Function keys *before* needing them?
Recently I encountered this phrase: "try the usual keys to bring this up on boot such as F1, F2, F10,(be aware that some manufacturers use F10 for system recovery!) Esc, or Del?"
I have run into some variation of this many, many times before (and always snarled in frustration) but for the first time wondered--is there a way to ask (command-line or otherwise) before one is in trouble, to have this kind of information listed, rather than relying on trial and error?
Thanks!

If you're talking about function keys 'pre-boot' for getting into the bios/UEFI firmware or the boot selection, they tend to be 'specific' to the firmware maker. If the OS boots, there's commands that might work. Generically function keys don't get used much day to day in modern systems in my experience, unless its application specific.

When you say 'firmware', are you referring to the manufacturer of the computer (ie, HP or Lenovo) or to the manufacturer of the motherboard?

Each manufacturer has their own standards for F-keys. For example one uses F2 for BIOS and F12 for boot order, another F9 and F10. Moral: RTFM (read the fine manual)

The question was less, “Where is the information?” than, “Can the computer provide that information itself?”
It seems ironic that it can perform an action in response to a Function key, but cannot list the possible actions linked to each key.

No, there isn't a universal standard key combination for showing unstandardised key combinations.
It seems unsurprising to me that the former is either unavailable or as unstandardised as the latter. Admittedly, this might just be a result of the corrosive effect, on my degree of cynicism, of long exposure to IT manufacturer shenanigans.

After 'long exposure to IT manufacturers', can one still call it cynicism?
